# Generate different tables in same page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an html with a table populated with data fetched from a MySql database.

I have the values in one column as hrefs that have an id which is the element id in the DB.

```
<td $se_color class=\"uk-text-center uk-table-middle uk-table-middle\"  rowspan=\"$se_rowspan\"><a href=??? id="$se_id">$se_name</a></td>
```

What do i place on the href attribute? #?

What do i need to do so that when the user clicks the link, I can generate another table based on the href's id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you `echo` the `td` tag you have in your question. Try doing it with this syntax instead:

```
echo '<td ' . $se_color . ' class="uk-text-center uk-table-middle uk-table-middle"  rowspan="' . $se_rowspan . '"><a href="page.php?se_id=' . $se_id . '" id="' . $se_id . '">' . $se_name . '</a></td>';
```

Notice `href="page.php?se_id=' . $se_id . '"` in the anchor tag.

In *page.php* you can get the value with:

```
$se_id = $_GET['val1'];
```

and thereafter get data from the DB via these values.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try that! Tks